# File upload form not valid

Tags: django, validation, file-upload

I have a file upload form which I can not get to validate successfully.
The form loads fine and I can upload a file but after 'submit' I can not get past Fileform.is_valid() in the view. I have mostly copies this view and the model and form model from the Django 1.9 [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/) documentation  but I must be missing something.

The view.py is,

```
def file_sharing_form(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    file = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if file.is_valid():
        fform = file.save(commit=False)
        fform.author = request.user
        fform.pub_date = timezone.now()
        fform.submitted_date = timezone.now()
        fform.approved = False
        fform.save()
        # email admin
        admin_email = User.objects.all().filter(is_superuser = True)
        subject = 'File submitted to QQIresources, awaiting approval'
        to_email = admin_email[0].email
        from_email = request.user.email
        message = 'A file has been submitted to QQIresources by ' + str(request.user) + ' and is awaiting admin approval. \n \n Title: ' + str(fform.title) + '\n Author: ' + str(fform.author) + '\n Description: ' + str(fform.description)
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to_email])
        return redirect('init')
fileform = FileForm()
return render(request, 'file_form.html', {'fileform': fileform})
```

Comment: I know the variable names are close but I think what I am using is correct Fileform = FileForm(.... Lower case 'f' for form in the first and uppercase 'F' in Form for the second. Thanks

Comment: I will change it to make them more distinct. But this is not the problem, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have missed enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html. Please add this in your form definition for any type of file upload.

```
<form action="{% url 'your_url' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file">
</form>
```

Comment: I did read about enctype="multipart/form-data" in the documentation but I thought it would be handles in the form. Obviously not, working now thanks

Comment: You are Welcome :) @ofey